# How to import a complete csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv

**Here is my Code :**

```
setwd('C:/Users/Arishma.Datta/Desktop/Mock Project/IP 10/4. Data')

data_1 = read.csv("data.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
```

for some unfathomable reason only top 146 obs is being read out of 250000 obs. 
Please help

Comment: no reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

if you have strings/text in your data, try adding
data_1 = read.csv("data.csv", header = T, sep = ",",quote='"')

because this is comma-separated, make sure that columns with text (especially those that might have commas in it) are wrapped in quotes.

if there are more columns than expected in the top 146, make sure that every row has a line break.

it would be easier to debug if you could post the first few lines of your data in plain text...